# What is the accuracy of a Minecraft dispenser?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to know how accurate a dispenser can be for defensive purposes.
There are facts for arrows fired from bows in the Minecraft wiki, but not for dispensers. The reason being dispensers can be automatically fired at a high rate without stopping.

 If anyone can figure it out then it will help with the distance and percentage of stopping power for any enemies wanting to hurt you. Here is the range of data I need in order to start a small range of research for now.

- Target distance range: 5-20
- Target level range: -20-20
- Target size is 2 (vertical)